# Crop section of image without sticking out

Tags: html, css

I am successfully achieving my goal but in so doing the divs stick outside the normal area and require scrolling. How can I achieve this sort of masking while keeping everything contained horizontally. I've tried altering the position of various elements and can't seem to achieve this goal. *Note the colors are only there for reference, in the end the red/blue/green divs would be white.

https://jsfiddle.net/xevsz81c/

```css
#leftDivider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
 }
 #leftDivider div{
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 0 60px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 100%;
 }
 #rightDivider {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
 }
 #rightDivider div{
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 50px 60px;
  border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  right: 100%;
 }
 .divider {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
 }
  .row {background: orange; position: relative; height: 300px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
  html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    This div has a background image
 <div class="divider"><div id="leftDivider"><div></div></div></div>
 <div class="divider"><div id="rightDivider"><div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having a difficult time recreating the issue in your fiddle, might be a lack of the image within the orange div. But try the following:

You would have to utilize the `overflow: hidden` property.

By doing this you hide the extra and disable the scrolling which sounds like what you need and are experiencing.

See the [explanation here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) as well as its uses.

Comment: Wow. I'm trying too hard. Here I am positioning and moving and blah blah blah and I forget the simple overflow property. *facepalm*

Comment: I think as developers we start to walk into problems expecting disaster. I share your facepalm on many occasions. Hopefully you resolved. Cheers

Comment: Still working on centering the "arrow" part of the mask, but I think I'll get it.